# PSake Error Executing MSBuild Command

Tags: msbuild, psake

I have 3 projects in the solution,
A WPFApplication and 2 ClassLibrary projects
When i build the Solution i get error below..

```
properties { 
    $base_dir = resolve-path . 
    $build_dir = "$base_dir\build" 
    $buildartifacts_dir = "$build_dir\BuildArtifacts" 
    $sln_file = "$base_dir\Hello.sln" 
} 

task default -depends Compile 

task Clean { 
    Write-Host "Cleaning solution" -ForegroundColor Green 
    remove-item -force -recurse $buildartifacts_dir -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue 
} 

task Init -depends Clean { 
    Write-Host "Creating BuildArtifacts directory" -ForegroundColor Green 
    new-item $buildartifacts_dir -itemType directory 
} 


task Compile -depend Init { 
   Write-Host "Compiling ---" $sln_file -ForegroundColor Green 
   Exec { msbuild $sln_file "/p:OutDir=$build_artifacts_dir" 
/p:Configuration=Release /v:quiet } 

}
```

i get the following error's -- what am i doing wrong?

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2868­,9): 
>   error MSB3023: No destination specified for Copy. Please supply either "DestinationFiles" or "DestinationFolder". [D:\Nusrofe\GrokPSake2\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3471­,9): 
>   error MSB4044: The "FindUnderPath" task was not given 
>    a value for the required parameter "Path". [D:\Nusrofe\GrokPSake2\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2868­,9): 
>   error MSB3023: No destination specified for Copy. Ple 
>   ase supply either "DestinationFiles" or "DestinationFolder". [D:\Nusrofe\GrokPSake2\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj]
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3471­,9): 
>   error MSB4044: The "FindUnderPath" task was not given 
>    a value for the required parameter "Path". [D:\Nusrofe\GrokPSake2\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj]
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(3471­,9): 
>   error MSB4044: The "FindUnderPath" task was not given 
>    a value for the required parameter "Path". [D:\Nusrofe\GrokPSake2\WpfApp\WpfApp.csproj]

---

> build2.ps1:Error executing command:  msbuild $sln_file 
>   "/p:OutDir=$build_artifacts_dir" /p:Configuration=Release /v:quiet

Thanks -- 
Corku

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your `Compile` task you have a stray underscore in your `$buildartifacts_dir` variable.  MSBuild probably doesn't know what to do because essentially you are passing it an empty location for the OutDir.